# How can I rip audio from an audio CD in .bin format?

Tags: cd, cd-ripping

I've downloaded the .bin, .cue and .cdt files of an audio CD ([freely available](http://www.mikedickson.org.uk/mellotronworks/index.html)), but I'd prefer to have the audio in FLAC format on my computer. How do I convert the audio tracks of the .bin file to FLAC files without losing quality?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4):

(Expanding on the [solution from oldmankit over at Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1504325&s=215337907ffa03169a1db55f93432936&p=9951058#post9951058))

1. Install bchunk and flac:

   ```
   sudo apt install bchunk flac
   ```
2. Use bchunk to convert the .bin to WAV files:

   ```
   bchunk -w image.bin image.cue track
   ```
3. Use flac to compress the WAV files:

   ```
   for f in track*.wav; do flac $f; done
   ```

Naming and tagging the FLAC files is subject for another question, but cuetools (particularly the cueprint command) may be of help there.